# Are there any public MemberNotNull/MemberNotNullWhen attributes in .net core

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have read the following article about nullable reference analysis in C# 8 not long ago:
https://www.meziantou.net/csharp-8-nullable-reference-types.htm

The post-condition attributes are particularly interesting to me. Recently I have encountered a situation where it might be useful to apply `MemberNotNull` attribute. However, unexpectedly I can't find `MemberNotNull` and `MemberNotNullWhen` public attributes in the .Net core 3.1. However, I can see a number of internal attributes declared in .net core:
https://source.dot.net/#q=MemberNotNull

Are there any substitutions in .net core for these attributes. Do I have to use .net 5 to use them?

Comment: [`MemberNotNullWhenAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.membernotnullwhenattribute?view=net-5.0) was added in .NET 5, source can be found [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/NullableAttributes.cs,cabd008b3a116a14).

Comment: `MemberNotNull` can be found in [the same file](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/NullableAttributes.cs,135)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation. I provided the links to the sources of MemberNotNullWhenAttribute myself in the question. There are multiple declarations of the same attributes in different assemblies of .net core. I would like to avoid such declaration in my code if possible since it looks not very clean to me. More importantly I don't know if it will work with Roslyn.

Comment: I tried to copy declarations of both attributes to my code but it didn't work out. The warnings are still displayed.

Comment: Well, that's kind of obvious. The attributes by themselves don't do anything. You also need the tooling (Roslyn analyzers)

Comment: What tooling? Are null dereference Roslyn analyzers shipped outside of Roslyn as a separate package? Are they not an internal part of Roslyn?

Comment: The tooling comes with the SDK. You need the latest SDKs if you want to use the latest features. Types that were introduced in .NET 5 don't exist in .NET Core, so the best you can do is hack together an unsupported solution

Comment: It's hard to answer a person who deletes their own comments but keeps the downvote for a compiling answer.  But I will try. The original question was asking about the substitutes for attributes missing in the SDK. The hack solution wouldn't even work if Roslyn didn't already support internally `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.MemberNotNullWhenAttribute`. However, I'm asking because there could be a better solution to this unknown to me or a nuget package with missing attributes supported officially.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reference [Nullable](https://github.com/manuelroemer/Nullable) package. It will do basically the same as you did with copy-paste. Think that's the best way to backport these attributes to pre .net50 sdks.

Comment: same author did Init polyfill

Answer (score 3):

I tried to copy declarations of both attributes to my source code but it didn't help when I declared attributes in my custom namespace. However if I declare them in `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis` namespace like this then it works:

```
namespace System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public sealed class MemberNotNullWhenAttribute : Attribute
    {
        /// <summary>Initializes the attribute with the specified return value condition and a field or property member.</summary>
        /// <param name="returnValue">
        /// The return value condition. If the method returns this value, the associated parameter will not be null.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="member">
        /// The field or property member that is promised to be not-null.
        /// </param>
        public MemberNotNullWhenAttribute(bool returnValue, string member)
        {
            ReturnValue = returnValue;
            Members = new[] { member };
        }

        /// <summary>Initializes the attribute with the specified return value condition and list of field and property members.</summary>
        /// <param name="returnValue">
        /// The return value condition. If the method returns this value, the associated parameter will not be null.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="members">
        /// The list of field and property members that are promised to be not-null.
        /// </param>
        public MemberNotNullWhenAttribute(bool returnValue, params string[] members)
        {
            ReturnValue = returnValue;
            Members = members;
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the return value condition.</summary>
        public bool ReturnValue { get; }

        /// <summary>Gets field or property member names.</summary>
        public string[] Members { get; }
    }
}
```

And Roslyn removes the displayed warning for possible null dereference.
However, instead I receive the following error:

> Error CS8652: The feature 'MemberNotNull attribute' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version.

So it seems I can at least switch to the preview language version with this approach. But I would like to avoid such hacks, so if there is a better solution please provide it and I will mark it as an accepted answer.

EDIT: To avoid some confusion expressed in the comments - this answer allows to use `MemberNotNullWhen` attribute without compile time error. Just add

```
  <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
```

to your project file.

Comment: This doesn't cause compile time error if you switch to the language version "preview" as I described. Please read answer to the end.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to upgrade your framework version, or backport support for `[MemberNotNull]` from .NET 5, you can instead initialize the relevant fields using the null forgiving operator as a workaround.

For example, if you have a non-nullable field `_myField` that is initialized in the method `Init()`, you can add write the following in your constructor to remove the warning about a non-null value when exiting the constructor.

```cs
_myField = null!;
InitFields();
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have found the PolySharp project that allows to add all modern C# features that do not not require runtime support to solutions targeting older .Net frameworks:
https://github.com/Sergio0694/PolySharp

This includes the attributes provided by the Nullable package mentioned in the @unsafePtr answer but also `init` and `required` property accessors, records and many other things.

I've decided to add the link to the PolySharp project as a different answer because I feel that it's a different kind of answer from the manual implementation I have specified before.