# C# 8: specify nullability of property value via attributes for null state static analysis

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm working in ASP.NET core 3.1 with C# 8 and nullable reference types enabled via csproj attribute (`Nullable` tag in csproj file, with value `enable`).

I have a class similar to the following one:

```
public sealed class Product 
{
   // other code is omitted for brevity

   public bool HasCustomCode { get; }
   
   // this property is null when HasCustomCode is false
   public string? CustomCode { get; }
}
```

Some products have a custom code, some others have not. For products not having the custom code, the value returned by property `CustomCode` is `null`.

Is it possible to tell the C# compiler that each time the value of the property `HasCustomCode` is `true`, then the value of `CustomCode` is **not** null ? The idea is not having warnings about the nullability of `CustomCode` property when working with an instance for which `HasCustomCode` is `true`

Comment: I don't think there is anything in .NET Core 3.1 that will help. `MemberNotNullWhen` would be perfect here, but that's in .NET 5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any public MemberNotNull/MemberNotNullWhen attributes in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64975948/are-there-any-public-membernotnull-membernotnullwhen-attributes-in-net-core)

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64975948/are-there-any-public-membernotnull-membernotnullwhen-attributes-in-net-core) from unsafePtr:

> You can reference [Nullable](https://github.com/manuelroemer/Nullable) package. It will do basically the same as you did with copy-paste. Think that's the best way to backport these attributes to pre .net50 sdks.

Alternatively, you may take one of these approaches:

---

|- Give your data a meaningful default value

```
public sealed class Product
{
    public string CustomCode { get; } = String.Empty;

    public bool HasCustomCode => CustomCode != String.Empty;
}
```

---

|- Refactor the nullable data as a private member

```
public sealed class Product
{
   private string? customCode;
    
   public bool HasCustomCode => customCode != null;
   public string CustomCode  => customCode ?? String.Empty;
}
```

---

|- Use a meaningful extraction method

```
public sealed class Product
{
   private string? customCode;

   public bool HasCustomCode(out string customCode)
      => (customCode = this.customCode) != null;
}

if (p.HasCustomCode(out string code))
{

}
```

---

Best Regards :)